# Round up trailing 5 with Math.round

Tags: c#, rounding

The result of this code,

```
string leftVal = foo();
Math.Round((decimal)float.Parse(leftVal), 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

is `3285.812`, but I need `3285.813`.

How can I get the desired value?

Comment: No, no it's not. That returns the correct result. https://dotnetfiddle.net/0lV25j

Comment: Remember that all floating point numbers are (potentially) approximate. Was that value `3285.8125` the result of an earlier calculation? If so, it is most likely carrying additional precision that is hidden in your display, that makes the fiurth decimal ever so slightly less than a 5.

Comment: Pieter raises a good point. Are you sure the number isn't 3285.81249999999999? The `ToString` might be obscuring that if you've got it going through some special formatting.

Comment: Its giving  the required output.

Comment: I have added the actual code line to question. I think Pieters reason can be the cause for this. anyone know any fix for this?

Answer (score 3):

Rather than parsing the string as a `float` and then casting to a `decimal`, you should probably just parse it straight to a `decimal`:

```
string leftVal = foo();
Math.Round(decimal.Parse(leftVal), 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

It seems that the cast to decimal is what's rounding.